# Sacred 1: Change game difficulty

Tags: sacred

I'm playing Sacred (Gold) as a Battle Mage and am currently near the end of chapter 1.

I'm playing as some kind of fire mage with a lot of fire damage and use Fire Spiral for attacking (sometimes Purgatory for single targets out of my close range) and a combo for buffing me.

My kind of "problem" is that so far I haven't faced any real challenge. I'm not saying I'm a good player, I know the game for only a few days. But I started the game on "Bronze". My fire spiral is doing an insane amount of damage so that every enemy is dead within 2 seconds. Even special quest enemies die within a few seconds. My buffs grant me good protection and if I lose health I can spam potions.

I love the game so far! Nice classes, good skill system, good role-playing, but so far it's "too easy" because I play it on "Bronze".

**Does the game get more difficult in later chapters?**

**Is there any way to increase the difficulty in a running game without having to start from the beginning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is from memory, I haven't played the game in a long time.

Bronze is a difficulty meant mostly to learn how to play the game, and is rather easy.

I'm pretty sure the is no way to increase the difficulty without having to redo the quests. You should be able to switch to silver without loosing your items. And you can then rush through the quests to the place where you are now. Most quests don't even need you to kill enemies, just run past them. You can use this run-like-the-wind tactic now too. But you'll end up having to complete silver if you want to continue anyway. And if you first complete bronze, most of silver is a pushover since monsters are aimed for new characters.

I seem to remember the later area's being significantly harder then the earlier ones. Especially the expansion added area's.

Playing on silver difficulty will up the difficulty some, and allow you to unlock the next difficulty (gold, and then two more, but I forgot the names) when you beat the game.

Comment: So I can start a new game with my existing character? I would "reset" the world to a fresh world but keep my level, items, skills etc?

Comment: Yup. I forgot how exactly to do so though. You might have to try a "LAN" game to switch it. I don't remember that bit anymore. But you can definitely change your world without loosing anything from your character(except quest progress, that's linked to difficulty)!

Comment: Do you know if there is any *complete* wiki or community page for Sacred 1?

Comment: The most complete wiki you'll find is probably [sacredwiki](http://www.sacredwiki.org), made and maintained by the people over at [darkmatters](http://darkmatters.org). A lot of people from over there ended up with (multiple) references in sacred2 to them.